# What is the allocation strategy of the c++ priority_queue?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

If I push 5 elements into a c++ `priority_queue`，when i `pop()` one element from queue and then push one element into this queue, how many memory space will this queue use now? 5 or 6?

Comment: `5`.  `5 - 1 + 1 == 5`

Comment: The queue will certainly contain 5 elements. The exact amount of memory it takes up will depend on both the specific underlying container you use for the priority queue (by default it's `std::vector`), the specific implementation of that container, and how the OS actually responds to the memory instructions your code emits.

Comment: Answer: 5. Reason: You start with 5. Then you pop (subtract) one. Current 4. Then you push (add) one. 5 nodes.  As Nathan said: 5-1+1. Which is 5

Comment: The answer depends on your definition of _"...memory space..."_ please clarify this.

Comment: The underlying `vector` may very well double its size when necessary, which means that adding the 5th element reserved enough space for 8 elements (4*2). But this depends on the implementation. IIRC Microsoft uses 1,2,3,4,6,9,...

Comment: @sweenish Can you elaborate on how you'd test this? I don't believe the `std::priority_queue` type has an interface to get the underlying container, and even if it did that container doesn't necessarily reveal how much memory it uses.

Comment: @wwb1 To clarify, is your question how many total bytes of memory would be used by the `std::priority_queue`? How much space for elements the `std::priority_queue` would be using? Whether the removed elements are still stored somewhere? Something else? Happy to answer once I have a better sense of what you're looking for. :-)

Comment: From one perspective, a `priority_queue` uses no space directly, as it delegates that responsibility to the underlying container. In this respect, the question would be better framed if it asked about `std::vector` or `std::deque` instead of `std::priority_queue`.

Comment: @templatetypedef my question is how many memory will be used by priority-queue,not elements in the queue used.further，I want to know the underlying vector use how much space

Comment: @templatetypedef I was going to reply, and realized I must have made a mod feel things, as my comment has been removed. It's also been rendered moot by OP clarifying what they meant. The power trip is real here,  isn't it.